# Is it safe to redirect non ssl requests to ssl version of site?

Tags: ssl

There is an API. Earlier all request were made not via ssl connection (encription was used) - `http://api.com/dosomething`. Logic has changed now. Now it is a bit problem to change URL for all clients who are using this API. There is https version of the API site. Is it safe to redirect all requests `http://api.com/dosomething` to `https://api.com/dosomething` on server side (Apache or nginx)? How it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your API consumer transmits everything in the clear: All its data, authentication, etc. And on your new server you're redirecting to the "same" URL, just using https? The https connection now will be secure, but all of your data and authentication has long leaked.

As we don't know anything about your API consumer, technically it could be a web browser that honors "secure" cookies, e.g. it might not transmit the authentication in the clear. But still, all of the data will be out already. As you say that you can't update the clients, I'm assuming that you're not in this situation.

So: The answer is no, it's not secure. Retire the old API, keep track of anyone accessing it. Once they're few enough, notify them of discontinuing the http service so that they upgrade. Or stay unsafe - choose your poison.

Comment: Probably, not the best way formed question, but thank you for a good answer. I've chosen my poison. ) Retirement.